# Search feature by attribute and show centered on map in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, features, zoom

I have a layer in OpenLayers and I would like that, when clicked to become visible, it shows a text box or something similar, so that the user can enter a code.

Then, when the layer is shown on the map, show the layer with the feature with the searched code highlighted in a zoom 18. Any idea?

```
    var my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Quadra Fiscal',
    visible: false,
    style: my_style,
    }),
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});

my_layer.on('change:visible', function(){ 
    if (my_layer.getVisible() == true){
        if (map.getView().getZoom() >= 17) {
            alert('zoom ok')
            /*my_layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
                //HERE: if feature.get(COD) equals code entered, center to that feature
            });*/               
        } else {
            alert('Verify  the zoom')
            my_layer.setVisible(false)
        } 
        
    }   
})
```

Comment: Even though you've been here a while, you haven't yet taken the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. A "How to *this* and *that*" Question title is likely to attract closure votes for lack of *focus*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is:

Create the text input field with a HTML ID attribute.
On change of the textbox get its contents (via `document.getElementById(...).value` ). Iterate over the layer features, if your attribute value matches the input field value get the feature, apply a specific style to it (to mark it as selected) and zoom and pan to its centroid.

Comment: Thanks, thanks for the help.